how to do border in box plot?
That is a random data
set.seed(123)

# Number of rows in the dataset
num_rows <- 100

# Generate random dataset with 4 columns
random_dataset <- data.frame(
  A = runif(num_rows),          # Random numbers for column A
  B = runif(num_rows),          # Random numbers for column B
  C = runif(num_rows),          # Random numbers for column C
  D = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Child"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)  # Random values for column D
)

# Display the first few rows of the dataset
head(random_dataset)



 library(ggplot2)
    
    # Generate the bar plot with a black border around the bars
    ggplot(random_dataset, aes(x = D, y = A)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = A - sd_A, ymax = A + sd_A),
    width = 0.2,
    color = "black"
  ) + 
  labs(title = "Bar Plot of Column A",
       y = "Values for Column A",
       x = "Category D") +
  theme_classic()

now when I run this data my picture looks like this
All i want i proper bar diagram with error bars and just a border on each bar

Do you want a boxplot (as suggested by your title) or a barplot?

I think you need this: We have to do some pre-calculation:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

random_dataset %>%
  summarise(sum_A = sum(A), sd_A = sd(A), .by=D) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = D, y = sum_A)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = sum_A - sd_A, ymax = sum_A + sd_A), width = 0.1) 


